# Java FX populate tableview with specific model

Tags: java, javafx, controller

Hello I have got a question about TableView in JavaFX and populating the table with data from an object **in** the model via a *getter method* of this object, which **is part of** the model .

First of all, here is my model:

```
   package model;

import java.util.List;


public class Carmodel {

    private int carmodelID;
    private Cartype cartype;
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
    private DrivingLicense drivingLicense;
    private String label;
    private int seats;
    private int kw;
    private String fuelType;
    private double priceDay;
    private double priceKM;
    private int axes;
    private int loadVolume;
    private int loadCapacity;
    private List<Equipment> equipmentList;


    public Carmodel() {


    }

    public int getCarmodelID() {
        return carmodelID;
    }

    public void setCarmodelID(int carmodelID) {
        this.carmodelID = carmodelID;
    }

    public Cartype getCartype() {
        return cartype;
    }

    public void setCartype(Cartype cartype) {
        this.cartype = cartype;
    }

    public Manufacturer getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

public void setManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}

public DrivingLicense getDrivingLicense() {
    return drivingLicense;
}

public void setDrivingLicense(DrivingLicense drivingLicense) {
    this.drivingLicense = drivingLicense;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public int getSeats() {
    return seats;
}

public void setSeats(int seats) {
    this.seats = seats;
}

public int getKw() {
    return kw;
}

public void setKw(int kw) {
    this.kw = kw;
}

public String getFuelType() {
    return fuelType;
}

public void setFuelType(String fuelType) {
    this.fuelType = fuelType;
}

public double getPriceDay() {
    return priceDay;
}

public void setPriceDay(double priceDay) {
    this.priceDay = priceDay;
}

public double getPriceKM() {
    return priceKM;
}

public void setPriceKM(double priceKM) {
    this.priceKM = priceKM;
}

public int getAxes() {
    return axes;
}

public void setAxes(int axes) {
    this.axes = axes;
}

public int getLoadVolume() {
    return loadVolume;
}

public void setLoadVolume(int loadVolume) {
    this.loadVolume = loadVolume;
}

public int getLoadCapacity() {
    return loadCapacity;
}

public void setLoadCapacity(int loadCapacity) {
    this.loadCapacity = loadCapacity;
}

public List<Equipment> getEquipmentList() {
    return equipmentList;
}

public void setEquipmentList(List<Equipment> equipmentList) {
    this.equipmentList = equipmentList;
}
```

As you can see there is a specific member (private Manufacturer manufacturer) It is an object  from the type "Manufacturer". And the Manufacturer class looks like this:

```
public class Manufacturer {

private int manufacturerID;
private String name;

public Manufacturer() {
}


public int getManufacturerID() {
    return manufacturerID;
}

public void setManufacturerID(int manufacturerID) {
    this.manufacturerID = manufacturerID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

This is my controller for the JavaFX View:

```
public class CarmodelController implements Initializable {


CarmodelRepository carmodelRepository;
@FXML public TableView CarmodelTable;
@FXML public TableColumn<Carmodel,Integer> tableColumnID ;
@FXML public TableColumn<Carmodel,String> tableColumnLabel ;
@FXML public TableColumn<Carmodel, String> tableColumnManufacturer ;
@FXML public TableColumn<Carmodel,String> tableColumnCartype ;




public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


    carmodelRepository= new CarmodelRepository();

    List<Carmodel> carmodelList= carmodelRepository.readAll();

    ObservableList<Carmodel> carmodelObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(carmodelList);



    tableColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Carmodel, Integer>("carmodelID"));
    tableColumnLabel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Carmodel, String>("label"));
    tableColumnManufacturer.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Carmodel, String>("manufacturer")
```

And here is the problem:

1. Can I do here something like PropertyValueFactory("manufacturer.getName()"); This way it didn't work. It just populate the column of the table with memory adress

So my question is:

How can I get the name of the manufacturer, normally, in other code, you can do this by calling the method: "manufacturer.getName();" and it will give you the String with the name of the manufacturer, but how can I do this while I will populate the table with these specific carmodels?

And the end of the controller code ( filling the Table with values).

```
    CarmodelTable.setItems(carmodelObservableList);

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
tableColumnManufacturer.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getManufacturer().getName());
```

The `setCellValueFactory` method expects a `Callback<CellDataFeatures<Carmodel, String>, ObservableValue<String>>` object. Hence `cellData` in this code is a `CellDataFeatures<Carmodel, String>` object, and `cellData.getValue()` gives the `CarModel` object for the row. Then `cellData.getValue().getManufacturer().getName()` gives the value you want; you just have to wrap it in a `ReadOnlyObservableWrapper` to get an `ObservableValue<String>` containing that value.